# MSSQL+XAMPP+php connection issue

Tags: php, sql-server, odbc

i am get a strange problem - i cant connect to mssql server with php script, and them totally not response:
I am using:

```
<?php
$myServer = "WIN-1AA0FSC1ASQ\SQLEXPRESS";
$myUser = "sa";
$myPass = "testpwd123";
$myDB = "mydatabase";

//connection to the database
$dbhandle = mssql_connect($myServer, $myUser, $myPass)
  or die("Could not connect to database: ".mssql_get_last_message());
?>
```

But error is : Warning: mssql_connect() [function.mssql-connect]: Unable to connect to server: WIN-1AA0FSC1ASQ\SQLEXPRESS in C:\xampp\htdocs\test.php on line 8
Could not connect to database:

No logs... i am tired to connect, type a wrong password - nothing... totally nothing.
Also, i am check my php.ini, included ddls...That is fresh installed XAMPP 1.7.1 version.
And some strange fact - ODBC Connect - works like a charm! But for mssql_conect - no reaction, inside MSSQL manager - no any logs about connection or error etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
$myServer
```

contains the Server (e.g. ip-address) and port information, not the database instance.

E.g. my MS SQL is listening on localhost, Port 1433. The provided $serverName is

```
$myServer = "127.0.0.1, 1433";
```

And here is the entire connection information:

```
$connectionInfo = array( "UID"=>$myUser,
                     "PWD"=>$myPass,
                     "Database"=>$myDB,
                     'ReturnDatesAsStrings'=>true);
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $myServer, $connectionInfo);
```

Cheers!